# How can I get the actual div selected in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I want to get an array from the total amount of div class "ritmo", and then print it (just for now, it's for some other purpose), but I don't know how to select the actual div position. How can I make it? What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!
Code:

```
<div class="ritmo" class="r1"></div>
<div class="ritmo" class="r2"></div>
<div class="ritmo" class="r3"></div>
<div class="ritmo" class="r4"></div>
<div class="ritmo" class="r5"></div>
<div class="ritmo" class="r6"></div>

<script>
$(".ritmo").click(function(){
    var ritmo = $(".ritmo");
    $(".ritmo").css("background-color","transparent");
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
    alert(ritmo[this]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend to read http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/. Also, what do you expect `alert(ritmo[this]);` to do?

Comment: Really cant understand what you are trying to ask..!

Comment: You can't have two `class` attributes in the same element. If an element has multiple classes, you need to put them in one attribute, like `class="ritmo r1"`.

Comment: `ritmo[this]` makes no sense. `this` is a DOM element. The index of an array must be an integer.

Comment: two class in div will not work class="ritmo" class="r1"

Comment: @KarthikManoharan I already said that

Comment: Allright, didn't knew about that, thanks. How can I put all the ritmo class into an array now?

Comment: Sorry i does not see that  Barmar

Comment: A jQuery collection can be accessed as an array. If you need an array of the original DOM elements, you can use `$(".ritmo").get()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get position of clicked div , use index method, as index method is zero-idex based , so you need to add 1 to final result.

```
$(".ritmo").click(function(){
    var ritmo = $(this);
    $(".ritmo").css("background-color","transparent");
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
    alert(ritmo.index()+1);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/ELFvT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This part is fine:

```
var ritmo = $(".ritmo");
```

Now the question still remains what you are trying to do with this?
Also if you require multiple classes you add them like this

```
class="One Two Three"
```

Just add a space between them.

Now if you need the length you can just do

```
alert(ritmo.length);
```

Also if you going to have nested elements you will have to probably add different class names to differentiate or do something like this.

```
var elements = $(this).children();
```

It will collect all nested CHILDREN of the div RITMO

Best of luck I hope this gives you enough fire power to take on what ever is that you are trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

See this to store all `div`s with `class=ritmo` into array :

```
var ritmo = $.makeArray($('.ritmo'));
```

For more information on `makeArray` click [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/).

**Note** : remove duplicate attribute `class` from each `div`. It should be like

```
<div class="ritmo r1"></div>
```